# Cannot access property of object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, properties

Pretty straightforward question, not sure what I've got wrong syntactically here.

[image]

```
const options: object[] = [
    { value: 0, label: 'Ab' },
    { value: 1, label: 'A' },
    { value: 2, label: 'Bb' },
    { value: 3, label: 'B' },
    { value: 4, label: 'C' },
    { value: 5, label: 'Db' },
    { value: 6, label: 'D' },
    { value: 7, label: 'Eb' },
    { value: 8, label: 'E' },
    { value: 9, label: 'F' },
    { value: 10, label: 'Gb' },
    { value: 11, label: 'G' }
]
console.log(options[1].value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an interface for the objects:

```
interface Item { value: number, label: string };

const options: Item[] = [
...
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That's how TypeScript knows what properties (and their types) should be in an object. Thanks!